# PHP: issue with comparing variables

Tags: php, variables, compare, strcmp

I have two PHP variables that can either be empty (i.e. `value=""`) or contain a name in the format Last, First with a comma and a space between the last and first name (e.g. Mouse, Mickey).

I would like to make a simple check here and say if a variable is not empty AND is equal to another then check a checkbox but this doesnt work. 
Can someone here show me what I am doing wrong (in the below example the checkbox should be checked) ?

My problem is that the checkbox always gets checked, even if the variables don't match.

**Example:**

```
$poc1 = "Mouse, Mickey"; // hard-coded for testing
$poc2 = "Mouse, Mickey"; // hard-coded for testing

<input type="checkbox" id="check2" name="Copy_POC" <?php if(($poc2 != "") && (strcmp($poc2,$poc1))) { echo "checked"; } ?> />
```

Many thanks for any help with this, Tim.

Comment: Whats the error you get?

Comment: Just updated this above. No error, it just checks it always.

Comment: http://php.net/in_array - and if it is too complicated: wrap it in a function of it's own. You then can fix that function and all code that calls that function automatically works correct :)

Comment: Thanks. How about strcmp as I only want to compare two variables, not more ?

Comment: @user2571510: Wrap it in a function first. Then test for all you need to test. Show how far you come with  your question and the pin-point to the exact point of problem you have with that code / logic. So far the general answer is: Do the string comparison the way you like to compare the strings - PHP has many string and comparison functions.

Comment: Strange, but your code is working fine for me ! May be PHP versions issue?

Comment: And to debug an expression, you can use var_dump, too: `var_dump(($poc2 != "") && (strcmp($poc2,$poc1)));` - see https://eval.in/private/ef7423e94d61b2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look at the function signature for `strcmp`, and its return values:

```
int strcmp ( string $str1 , string $str2 )
```

So the function returns an int, but what kind of int? According to the manual:

> Returns < 0 if str1 is less than str2; > 0 if str1 is greater than str2, and 0 if they are equal.

In other words: if both strings are equal, `strcmp` returns `0`, which evaluates to `false`. What you should've written therefore is:

```
strcmp($str1, $str2) !== 0
```

This will evaluate to true if the 2 strings do not match. Of course, you only want to see the ckeckbox checked when the two strings *don't* match:

```
if ($str1 != '' && strcmp($str1, $str2) === 0)
{
    //checked
}
```

That ought to do it. Of course, this still relies on your calling functions to check these strings being equal. That doesn't really add up, though, and it might be a lot easier to just write:

```
if ($str1 && $str1 === $str2)
//an empty string is falsy + type & value check on 2 strings using === operator
```

*Note*
As you may already know, PHP is built on C, and therefore has a lot of C-like `str*` functions. Whenever you see a function like `strcmp` and `strstr`, check its return value. Like the C `string.h` functions, it often returns *either* a pointer (part of the string where substring is found, like `strstr`), or an integer (index/offset in string)...

Comment: Perfect, yes, that's exactly what I was missing ! Haven't used this function before. Thanks a lot ! :) Will accept as soon as I can.

Comment: If that is the answer, you're perhaps looking for: `$str1 === $str2` or `$str1 == $str2` first. In PHP you can compare strings with comparison operators, too.

Comment: @hakre: was about to edit my answer to add that, too :)

Comment: I love to use variables for that: `$checked = in_array($str1, array("", $str2));` new line `if ($checked) { ...` :)

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem: Just to confirm, I want the checkbox to be checked when both variables DO match. Looks like this was written the other way above ;-) .

Comment: @user2571510: Thought so, that's why I edited my initial answer... but even so: just using the `===` or even `==` operator will be easiest of all

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if($poc2 && $poc2 === $poc1) echo "checked" ?>
```